# OnClick on a specifc square in a photo. HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i want to add an OnClick event when the mouse is over a specific square in the picture.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML **map** element with the **img** element.
You need to define a map element which contains the location and the shape of each area you need to add the onclick events. Then use that map with relevant img element.
E.g:

```
<img src="menu.jpg" width="150" height="150" usemap="#menumap" />

<map name="menumap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,10,10" alt="home" href="#" onclick="go_home();"/>
  <area shape="rect" coords="20,20,30,30" alt="link2" href="#" onclick="do_link2();"/>
</map>
```

For **shape "rect"** which is the shape of a rectangle, **coords** attribute specifies the coordinates of the left, top, right, bottom corner of the rectangle (top left corner of the image is the x=0,y=0 point for these coordinates).

Comment: what if i want multiply maps? can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple maps? You can declare several clickable region in a single map for a image. I updated the code for having multiple areas for a one map. Check whether it is the thing you meant by multiple maps.

Answer (score -1):

Check for the mouses x and y position relative to the element

```
$('#example1').click(function(e){
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    ...
});
```

Comment: What does jQuery have to do with anything?